# Breakdown of iPhone users by phone generation

Tags: iphone, statistics

Now that the 3.0 OS & 3Gs are coming out, there will be a wider range in hardware and also in functional limitations (No P2P on first gen iDevices. No compass on anything but iPhone 3Gs, etc.) of users that will be buying our apps.

In the same way that W3schools has it's browser stats page (http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp), are there any sites that track the iPhone/iPod Touch user landscape?

Ideally we should all be developing for the latest and greatest and degrading, but it'd still be nice to have the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pinch Media](http://www.pinchmedia.com/#pinchanalytics) no doubt has this information.  I remember seeing a blog post from them with some analysis of different data.  They are a very responsive company, I wouldn't be surprised if you emailed them and asked if they'd point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm still waiting to hear back from them, but this is the best answer I've received.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the best place to get a close approximation of such statistics would be one of the cellular providers that offer the iPhone, given that they probably collect detailed customer information. As to whether these providers are able to give you this information is another matter altogether